# Issues with PnP.Powershell Get-PnPfile

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have been getting the following error while using the cmdlet `Get-PnPFile`.

> Get-PnPFile : The property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' has not been
> initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been
> executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-PnPFile -Url $fileURL -Path $downloadPath -Filename Leavers.CSV - ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFile], PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFile
>   ```

The code in question is bellow:

```
$siteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleSite"
$fileURL = "/sites/ExampleSite/Path/To/The/File.csv"
$downloadPath = "C:\Temp"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
Get-PnPFile -Url $fileURL -Path $downloadPath -Filename File.CSV -AsFile
```

The odd part is that it has previously worked and even now seems to work intermittently but more often than not it seems to error and I haven't been able to identify a pattern.

The `Connect-PnPOnline` command runs without error but doesn't seem to work correctly the majority of the time. I have been using `Get-PnPSite` to check the connection to the SharePoint site but it doesn't seem to be populating after the connection is made as shown bellow.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PNPsite

Url                                                     CompatibilityLevel                                                                                                                                                                                       
---                                                     ------------------
```

On the odd occasions when the `Get-PnPFile` command works the two fields above are populated correctly.

I have been googling this issue and have found some other people who have had success adding a variable to the start of either the `Get-PnPFile` cmdlet or the `Connect-PnPOnline cmdlet` Like so:

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileURL -Path $downloadPath -Filename File.CSV -AsFile
```

But this hasn't worked for me. I have also tried down and upgrading the version of PnP.Powershell From 1.8.0 to 1.8.11 and back down to 1.7.0 but this also hasn't had any effect.

Hope someone out there has some answers! Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you specify the absolute URL? Try `Get-PnPFile -Url "${siteURL}${fileURL}" -Path $downloadPath -Filename File.CSV -AsFile`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm afraid it produces the same error message as it did previously!